# about updation of ubuntu through update manager

Tags: updates, update-manager

when i check updates in update manager their are updates divide in some categories like important security update, recommended update and so on.

should we install all the updates in important security updates?

Please tell what settings a simple user should keep for update manager?

Comment: Personally I update everything. *There may come a time when a newer version is required to update the system and because you have not kept up to date with the less important files, the main update may cause problems.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should update recommended updates but you should care some package update which you dont want to update , like if you want to work on specific version of application then you should not update that application.

Comment: i not have such specific requirement but i want to know that update manager is shows files/software to update which are in my ubuntu os. because i have uninstall few application which are provided by ubuntu with ubuntu os.  Can someone tell me more about the settings/packages of update manager?